# How can I get last transaction details for every customer in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get the latest transaction for each customer from a **Mysql database** where each customer  may have a different number of transaction records.

**Here Mysql table:**

[image]

> This table  i have  mentioned the rows which have  bold (style), these
>   bold rows are last  transaction records.I want every customer last  transaction.

I except answer is below one.

[image]

I need mysql  query for  this selected records.

Comment: did you try something as max() and then use in the query ?

Comment: Yes you will need to use the Max aggregate and then group by the remainder of the columns you want to show

Comment: How can i get last two transaction records for every customer in customer table?
When I try to get last 5 transaction details for every customer I got this error
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
 
Query:
SELECT cus_id,
       tranc_amt,
       tranc_type,
       tranc_date
FROM cus_tranc where cus_id = (select distinct cus_id from customer)
ORDER BY tranc_date DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: Hi,I got solution in last n transaction.I have used 2 table.
SELECT customer.cus_id, customer.cus_name, temp.tranc_date, temp.tranc_amt
FROM customer
INNER JOIN
( SELECT tB1.tranc_date, tB2.cus_id,
    (
        SELECT tranc_amt
        FROM cus_tranc
        WHERE cus_tranc.tranc_date = tB1.tranc_date
    ) as tranc_amt
    FROM cus_tranc as tB1
        JOIN cus_tranc as tB2
            ON tB1.cus_id = tB2.cus_id AND tB1.tranc_date <= tB2.tranc_date
    GROUP BY tB1.cus_id, tB1.tranc_date
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
    ORDER BY cus_id, tranc_date desc
) as temp
ON customer.cus_id = temp.cus_id

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to take the `MAX` of your transaction date to find the most recent transaction. As this is an aggregate function you'll also want to `GROUP BY` your `cus_id`. This result then gives you the latest date for a customer so you can then join the rest of the data against that `cus_id` and `tranc_date` combination.

The query will look something like this:

```
SELECT cus_tranc.cus_id,
       cus_tranc.tranc_amt,
       cus_tranc.tranc_type,
       cus_tranc.tranc_date
FROM cus_tranc 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT cus_id,
         MAX(tranc_date) AS 'tranc_date'
  FROM cus_tranc
  GROUP BY cus_id) max_tranc ON cus_tranc.cus_id = max_tranc.cus_id AND cus_tranc.tranc_date = max_tranc.tranc_date
```

You can see the results of this in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4adf33/86).

Comment: Thanks ydaetskcoR, How can i get last two transaction records for every customer  in customer table?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but-- this answer is not right, you can see in the SQL Fiddle that you are getting 17-may for customer 1000 and tranc_type is 1. tranc type 1 is the one for 16 - may so this query mixes rows

Comment: @xzdead Good spot, I've updated my answer to actually be right!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT cus_id,
       tranc_amt,
       tranc_type,
       MAX(tranc_date) AS 'tranc_date'
FROM cus_tranc
GROUP BY cus_id
ORDER BY MAX(tranc_date)
```

Comment: The OP wanted the last transaction by the user of any type. This will only take the most recent transaction for a customer that is the same transaction type AND for the same amount which is pretty likely to return all of the table (and does in fact do this with the OP's example data).

Comment: Yes you are correct, I have edited my answer accordingly. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Bobby, How can i get last N transaction records for every customer in customer table

Comment: I don't think this is right, it mixes rows. You get the most recent date but tranc_amt and tranc_type are not the most recent

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cus_id,tranc_amt,tranc_type,tranc_date    
FROM cus_tranc    
WHERE tranc_date IN (SELECT MAX(tranc_date)
                     FROM cus_tranc
                     GROUP BY cus_id);
```

Comment: Try adding some context to your code to help future readers better understand its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple query will do the trick here,

```
SELECT cus_id, 
tranc_amt,
tranc_type,
MAX(tranc_date) as "tranc_date" 
FROM cus_tranc
GROUP BY cus_id
;
```

A simple grouping on customer ids, followed by selecting only the max value out of all possible dates per customer id.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RankedTransactions AS (
SELECT
    customer_id,
    transaction_id,
    transaction_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY transaction_date DESC) AS rn
FROM
    transactions ) 
 SELECT
   customer_id,
   transaction_id,
   transaction_date 
   FROM RankedTransactions
      WHERE
        rn <= 10;
```